# Select first child element within a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to select certain HTML elements to extract the text from an HTML document.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GentleMaN/kejbskc7/1/) link.

Is there a way to select only the first `<p>` element from specific divs in this scenario?

I only want the `<p>` elements that occur just before the links (first element after each of the parent divs), so only `Family Service of Middletown` and `Freestore Food Bank` would be red.

I know why the `jQuery :first-child` isn't working (because of the nested divs), but I'm not sure if there's a work-around.

```js
$("p:first-child").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyWrapper_60" class="agency income" data-display="closed">
                <p class="agency-title">Family Service of Middletown</p>
                <a href="http://www.fsmiddletown.org" id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyLink_60" class="agency-link" target="_blank">Visit Site</a>
                <div class="close-button"></div>
                <div class="programs">
                    
                            <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_60_ProgramWrapper_0" class="program income">
                       <div class="program-name">
                        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
                        <p class="program-description">Emergency Assistance (FSM)</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-allocation">
                        <p>Investment</p>
                        <p class="amount-allocated">$130,000.00 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-impact">
                        <p>Impact Area</p>
                                    <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-region">
                        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
                        <p class="region-area">Middletown Area</p>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                        
                </div>
            </div>


<div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyWrapper_61" class="agency income" data-display="closed">
                <p class="agency-title">Freestore Foodbank</p>
                <a href="http://www.freestorefoodbank.org" id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyLink_61" class="agency-link" target="_blank">Visit Site</a>
                <div class="close-button"></div>
                <div class="programs">
                    
                            <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_61_ProgramWrapper_0" class="program income">
                       <div class="program-name">
                        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
                        <p class="program-description">Power Pack - Newport KY</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-allocation">
                        <p>Investment</p>
                        <p class="amount-allocated">$28,112.00 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-impact">
                        <p>Impact Area</p>
                                    <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-region">
                        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
                        <p class="region-area">Northern Kentucky</p>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                        
                            <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_61_ProgramWrapper_1" class="program income">
                       <div class="program-name">
                        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
                        <p class="program-description">Client Services Project</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-allocation">
                        <p>Investment</p>
                        <p class="amount-allocated">$344,692.00 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-impact">
                        <p>Impact Area</p>
                                    <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-region">
                        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
                        <p class="region-area">Regional Center</p>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                        
                            <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_61_ProgramWrapper_2" class="program income">
                       <div class="program-name">
                        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
                        <p class="program-description">Cincinnati Cooks!</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-allocation">
                        <p>Investment</p>
                        <p class="amount-allocated">$39,156.00 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-impact">
                        <p>Impact Area</p>
                                    <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-region">
                        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
                        <p class="region-area">Regional Center</p>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                        
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Cant you just target `agency-title` $(".agency-title").css("color", "red");

Comment: @JSG The CSS is just to identify the correct element. I am actually trying to extract the text from the selected element (if you see the first sentence in my question). But I didn't event think of using the class selector. Wow - thanks.

Comment: @JSG is right. If all your "<p> elements that occur just before the links" have the class "agency-title", then just grab them with `$('.agency-title')`.

Comment: @Invent-Animate Then use the following: `$(".agency-title:first-child").text();` No need to make this complex.

Comment: @JSG Thank you - I really just didn't know how to do it.

Comment: @Invent-Animate No worries - no idea whats happening below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

> I only want the `<p>` elements that occur just before the links

By passing a function to `filter()`, we can use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to traverse to the next sibling. Because we pass the `a` selector, if the next element is an anchor, the length of the object returned will be 1:

```
$("p").hide().filter(function () {
    return $(this).next('a').length;
}).css("color", "red").show();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q1357Lch/1/)

---

For your specific scenario, since your elements have relevant classes, you can filter using them:

```
$("p").hide().filter('.agency-title').css("color", "red").show();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q1357Lch/5/)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks George! Can this be used to hide the other elements as well? (Not in my original question, I know)

Comment: Thanks George, I will accept as soon as the timer is up. I had meant hiding the other elements that aren't being selected.

Comment: @Invent-Animate OK, yes you could `.hide()` first and then `.show()` again your filtered object: http://jsfiddle.net/q1357Lch/4/

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution is to use jquery [**.prev()**](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```js
$("a").prev().css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyWrapper_60" class="agency income" data-display="closed">
  <p class="agency-title">Family Service of Middletown</p>
  <a href="http://www.fsmiddletown.org" id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyLink_60" class="agency-link" target="_blank">Visit Site</a>
  <div class="close-button"></div>
  <div class="programs">

    <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_60_ProgramWrapper_0" class="program income">
      <div class="program-name">
        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
        <p class="program-description">Emergency Assistance (FSM)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="program-allocation">
        <p>Investment</p>
        <p class="amount-allocated">$130,000.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="program-impact">
        <p>Impact Area</p>
        <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
      </div>
      <div class="program-region">
        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
        <p class="region-area">Middletown Area</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyWrapper_61" class="agency income" data-display="closed">
  <p class="agency-title">Freestore Foodbank</p>
  <a href="http://www.freestorefoodbank.org" id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyLink_61" class="agency-link" target="_blank">Visit Site</a>
  <div class="close-button"></div>
  <div class="programs">

    <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_61_ProgramWrapper_0" class="program income">
      <div class="program-name">
        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
        <p class="program-description">Power Pack - Newport KY</p>
      </div>
      <div class="program-allocation">
        <p>Investment</p>
        <p class="amount-allocated">$28,112.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="program-impact">
        <p>Impact Area</p>
        <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
      </div>
      <div class="program-region">
        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
        <p class="region-area">Northern Kentucky</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_61_ProgramWrapper_1" class="program income">
      <div class="program-name">
        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
        <p class="program-description">Client Services Project</p>
      </div>
      <div class="program-allocation">
        <p>Investment</p>
        <p class="amount-allocated">$344,692.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="program-impact">
        <p>Impact Area</p>
        <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
      </div>
      <div class="program-region">
        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
        <p class="region-area">Regional Center</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_61_ProgramWrapper_2" class="program income">
      <div class="program-name">
        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
        <p class="program-description">Cincinnati Cooks!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="program-allocation">
        <p>Investment</p>
        <p class="amount-allocated">$39,156.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="program-impact">
        <p>Impact Area</p>
        <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
      </div>
      <div class="program-region">
        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
        <p class="region-area">Regional Center</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Also you can be more specific in selector and be like:

```
$("div.agency a").prev().css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice short way to do it:

```
$("p + a").prev().css("color", "red");
```

```js
$("p + a").prev().css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyWrapper_60" class="agency income" data-display="closed">
                <p class="agency-title">Family Service of Middletown</p>
                <a href="http://www.fsmiddletown.org" id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyLink_60" class="agency-link" target="_blank">Visit Site</a>
                <div class="close-button"></div>
                <div class="programs">
                    
                            <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_60_ProgramWrapper_0" class="program income">
                       <div class="program-name">
                        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
                        <p class="program-description">Emergency Assistance (FSM)</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-allocation">
                        <p>Investment</p>
                        <p class="amount-allocated">$130,000.00 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-impact">
                        <p>Impact Area</p>
                                    <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-region">
                        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
                        <p class="region-area">Middletown Area</p>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                        
                </div>
            </div>


<div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyWrapper_61" class="agency income" data-display="closed">
                <p class="agency-title">Freestore Foodbank</p>
                <a href="http://www.freestorefoodbank.org" id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyLink_61" class="agency-link" target="_blank">Visit Site</a>
                <div class="close-button"></div>
                <div class="programs">
                    
                            <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_61_ProgramWrapper_0" class="program income">
                       <div class="program-name">
                        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
                        <p class="program-description">Power Pack - Newport KY</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-allocation">
                        <p>Investment</p>
                        <p class="amount-allocated">$28,112.00 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-impact">
                        <p>Impact Area</p>
                                    <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-region">
                        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
                        <p class="region-area">Northern Kentucky</p>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                        
                            <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_61_ProgramWrapper_1" class="program income">
                       <div class="program-name">
                        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
                        <p class="program-description">Client Services Project</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-allocation">
                        <p>Investment</p>
                        <p class="amount-allocated">$344,692.00 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-impact">
                        <p>Impact Area</p>
                                    <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-region">
                        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
                        <p class="region-area">Regional Center</p>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                        
                            <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_61_ProgramWrapper_2" class="program income">
                       <div class="program-name">
                        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
                        <p class="program-description">Cincinnati Cooks!</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-allocation">
                        <p>Investment</p>
                        <p class="amount-allocated">$39,156.00 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-impact">
                        <p>Impact Area</p>
                                    <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-region">
                        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
                        <p class="region-area">Regional Center</p>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                        
                </div>
            </div>
```

---

The `"p + a"` selects all `a` elements that have a `p` sibling directly before them. Then we just call `.prev()` to get back to the `p`.

---

And if you wanted to hide the other `p` elements, then do this:

```
$("p").hide().next("a").prev().show().css("color", "red");
```

```js
$("p").hide().next("a").prev().show().css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyWrapper_60" class="agency income" data-display="closed">
                <p class="agency-title">Family Service of Middletown</p>
                <a href="http://www.fsmiddletown.org" id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyLink_60" class="agency-link" target="_blank">Visit Site</a>
                <div class="close-button"></div>
                <div class="programs">
                    
                            <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_60_ProgramWrapper_0" class="program income">
                       <div class="program-name">
                        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
                        <p class="program-description">Emergency Assistance (FSM)</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-allocation">
                        <p>Investment</p>
                        <p class="amount-allocated">$130,000.00 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-impact">
                        <p>Impact Area</p>
                                    <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-region">
                        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
                        <p class="region-area">Middletown Area</p>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                        
                </div>
            </div>


<div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyWrapper_61" class="agency income" data-display="closed">
                <p class="agency-title">Freestore Foodbank</p>
                <a href="http://www.freestorefoodbank.org" id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyLink_61" class="agency-link" target="_blank">Visit Site</a>
                <div class="close-button"></div>
                <div class="programs">
                    
                            <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_61_ProgramWrapper_0" class="program income">
                       <div class="program-name">
                        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
                        <p class="program-description">Power Pack - Newport KY</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-allocation">
                        <p>Investment</p>
                        <p class="amount-allocated">$28,112.00 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-impact">
                        <p>Impact Area</p>
                                    <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-region">
                        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
                        <p class="region-area">Northern Kentucky</p>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                        
                            <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_61_ProgramWrapper_1" class="program income">
                       <div class="program-name">
                        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
                        <p class="program-description">Client Services Project</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-allocation">
                        <p>Investment</p>
                        <p class="amount-allocated">$344,692.00 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-impact">
                        <p>Impact Area</p>
                                    <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-region">
                        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
                        <p class="region-area">Regional Center</p>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                        
                            <div id="Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_ProgramsRepeater_61_ProgramWrapper_2" class="program income">
                       <div class="program-name">
                        <p class="program-title">Program</p>
                        <p class="program-description">Cincinnati Cooks!</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-allocation">
                        <p>Investment</p>
                        <p class="amount-allocated">$39,156.00 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-impact">
                        <p>Impact Area</p>
                                    <p class="impact-description">Families/Individuals achieve sustained employment</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="program-region">
                        <p class="region-title">Region</p>
                        <p class="region-area">Regional Center</p>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                        
                </div>
            </div>
```

---

It looks a little strange, but here's how it works:

- `$("p").hide()` Hide all `p` elements
- `.next("a")` Select the next sibling of each `p`, but only if it's an `a` element
- `.prev()` Now go back to the `p`, and it will be only the ones that had an `a` sibling
- `.show().css("color", "red")` Then show and color those remaining `p` elements

Comment: Thanks for explaining the `p + a` aspect - I am new.

Comment: @Invent-Animate: You're welcome. And if you wanted to hide the other `p` elements, then do this: `$("p").hide().next("a").prev().show().css("color", "red");`

Comment: Thank you. Looking at this - how do I hide the `a` elements? If I wanted to hide the hrefs.

Comment: @Invent-Animate: Oh, you wanted to hide the `a` elements and not the remaining `p` elements? If so, then before you use `.prev()` to traverse back to the `p`, just do `.hide()`.

Comment: No, no. What you had colored red is the only thing I wanted to select. I guess my wording was poor - sorry!!

Comment: @Invent-Animate: Sorry, I guess I'm not understanding. After you've colored them red, which elements do you want to hide?

Comment: Only the `p` element that is colored red is what I wanted to select. The red was just to identify the element that I was referring to. So, I only want the `<p>` with class `.agency-title` selected. Does that help? I suck at HTML, sorry.

Comment: @Invent-Animate: If you only want `p` elements with that class, then you'd do `$("p.agency-title")`

Comment: So, in your bottom code snippet - I wouldn't want the `Visit Site` href. Only the `<p>` tags. Does that make more sense? I will look into the `$("p.agency-title")` solutuon! Thank you

Comment: I actually found a kind of cool way, `$('p:not(.agency-title)').hide();
$( "a" ).hide();`

Comment: @Invent-Animate: You can do it in one selector: `$('p:not(.agency-title), a' ).hide();` or change the `, a` to `, p + a` to limit the `a` elements that are hidden.

Comment: Nice! That worked as well. I really appreciate your help. I gave everyone a +1.. that's the best I could do. I really do appreciate your help/explanation and discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.first()` instead of `.first-child()`:

```
 $("div[id*='Body_right_column_C013_AgenciesRepeater_AgencyWrapper_']").find('p:first').css("color", "red");
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/euhg8bwr/